# BigCommerce Stencil language files not working

Tags: bigcommerce

I've enabled stencil themes for my store, and am trying to use "Cornerstone" as my theme. However, the whole reason for opting in and trying out new stencil themes is their built in support for multiple languages. I need my store to at least be available in Swedish, and if possible, English as well.

I've followed the documentation adding a "sv.json" file to the langs folder, and uploaded the modified theme to my store and applied it. No changes. I've ensured my browser is setting the "Accept-Language" header to "sv".
https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/the-schema

I've also tried modifying the default en.json file, but I still can't see any changes in my store...and that seems a bit strange to me?

What am I missing, is this feature not really implemented yet, or am I screwing something up with the "upload zipped theme to store admin and apply"?
https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Custom-Theme-Upload

Any pointers are very appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using sv-fi or sv-se for the name instead of just sv? You also need to ensure you are invoking the translation keys: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/invoking-translation-keys

Comment: Yes, I've tried using sv-se as well as editing the default en.json file just to see if I can get any changes to appear. No changes is visible in the store what so ever...

Comment: so you make changes to cornerstone, use the stencil cli bundle command and upload that and don't see changes applied?

Comment: I just figured out that I needed to use the bundle command to create the zip. Wasn't all that clear in the "upload custom theme" documentation. Thank you anyway!